# App with action at some exact time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Suppose I have a model

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

My question is: what is the best practice to change attribute IsActive to true when the time determined in StartDate will come? Should I use delegates/events or Timer? I will be grateful for some short example.

The key thing is that IsActive is stored in the database, so on its' changing I would like the model to be updated in db.

Answer (score 2):

No timer is required because you don't need to set anything. Just write a property that calculates `IsActive`.

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsActive { get; } => DateTime.UtcNow >= StartDate;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what if I have this model stored in the database? How can I change it's value in db?

Comment: @VaskoYaroslav Why denormalize your data like this? How are you going to use this?

Comment: In different controllers I check SomeModel.IsActive to allow or not some actions.

Comment: So it's not necessary to duplicate this information. We always know when "now" is, so we don't need to explicitly code `IsActive` into our stored data.

Answer (score 0):

Make `IsActive` a calculated property.

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return DateTime.Now >= StartDate; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really would be best to use a property these other answers describe. You shouldn't have a column for IsActive in your Db since it can easily be calculated. That being said, if you need to process updates in your db like you're asking then you will need something like the following:

You should *not* do this from your actions as it will delay the response to the client, likely timeout, and consume resources.

What you probably want is a scheduler that performs the db updates while your .net core app is running. Since you can't rely on this being up all the time you will also need to process them on launch.

Consider a scheduler like these
- [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)
- [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler)

Define this function:

```
void UpdateActiveInDatabase(MyDbContext myDb){
    var models = myDb.myModels.Where(model => !model.IsActive && model.StartDate <= DateTime.UtcNow); //These models should be active
    foreach(var model in models) { model.IsActive = true; }
    myDb.SaveChanges();
}
```

Then, when your app starts:

```
var myDb = GetMyDb(); // Get a DbContext instance from your DI somewhere
UpdateActiveInDatabase();

var models = myDb.myModels.Where(model => model.StartDate > DateTime.UtcNow); //These models need to be updated in the future
foreach(var model in models){
    // Dependent on the scheduler you pick. Will need to get a DbContext from your DI and call UpdateActiveInDatabase(myDb);
}
```

And any time there is an update to the entities in your table, you also need `UpdateActiveInDatabase(myDb);`